# Nature of forces in damped oscillations

Tags: oscillators

What type of motion is seen in damped oscillation. It is definitely not simple harmonic motion but then time period of the motion is constant and amplitude keeps on decreasing so physically what is the nature of this motion like in shm the acceleration is directed in a fixed direction I.e mean position what are the nature of forces in damped motion

Comment: Damped motion also has the acceleration directed in a fixed direction. Just that it does not follow ${\vec a}=-k{\vec x}$

Comment: Where is the direction of force